# Evento onload JS

Tags: javascript

No consigo que se ejecute la función opciones() al cargar la página:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function opciones(){
            var id="cero";
            var n=10;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                document.getElementById(id).innerHTML+=
                    '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="cero" onload="opciones()">
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Lo he resuelto llamando directamente a la función, pero seguro que hay opciones mejores:

```
<select id="cero">
    <script>opciones()</script>
</select>
```

Comment: puedes usar JQuery, creando una funcion con `$(document).ready(function(){//Lo que quieras hacer al cargar})`, tambien si quieres ser mas purista de javascript puedes hacerlo como explica en [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp)

Comment: Perdon ¿para que es el segundo argumento de getElementById(id,n)? No lo encuentro en las especificaciones ¿es un error?

Comment: Era una errata, ya está corregida. El JS es tan permisivo que, aún así, funcionaba... :) Gracias por fijarte

Comment: El js es como una madre para todos nosotros, nos lo perdona todo ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de este modo:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script>
           document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",  function opciones(){
                var id="cero";
                var n=10;
                for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                    document.getElementById(id,n).innerHTML+=
                        '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="cero">
        </select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

- Remueve la llamada de la función de la etiqueta `select()` a través del evento `load` y usa el evento `DOMContentLoaded`
- `DOMContentLoaded` se invoca en cuanto el *documento HTML* esta cargado totalmente **(eso no incluye recursos extra al árbol DOM**
- A tu `document` agrégale un `listener` donde pasas como primer argumento el `DOMContentLoaded` por lo antes expuesto
- Como segundo argumento pasa la función `opciones` que ejecutará la lógica para poblar tu `select`

Answer (score 2):

La etiqueta `select` no soporta el evento `onload`. Pero puedes poner que la función se ejecute cuando la página cargue. `window.onload = opciones;`

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function opciones(){
            var id="cero";
            var n=10;
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
                document.getElementById(id,n).innerHTML+=
                    '<option value="'+i+'">'+i+'</option>';
        }
        
        window.onload = opciones;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="cero" onload="opciones">
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```